# why are Threads loading data from array randomly?

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading

I'm new with threads and I’m trying to create a program where four threads do some parallel computations using values from a global array. But, The problem that the threads are not loading the data in order.

```
#define QUARTER 64
#define RANGE_STEP 256

struct thread_data
{
  unsigned          start;
  unsigned          stop;
  __m256*           re_fc;
  __m256*           im_fc;
};

#define         NUM_THREADS                 4
struct          thread_data                 thread_data_array[NUM_THREADS];

void *routine(void *thread_info)
{
  int n,t;
  unsigned t_start,t_stop;
  __m256 *Re_fac    , *Im_fac;
  struct thread_data *mydata;
  mydata = (struct thread_data*) thread_info;
  t_start   = mydata->start;
  t_stop    = mydata->stop;
  Re_fac        = mydata->re_fc;
  Im_fac        = mydata->im_fc;

  t = t_start;
  for (n = t_start; n < t_stop; n += 8)
  {
    // computations
    RE_m256_fac = Re_fac[t];
    IM_m256_fac = Im_fac[t]; 
    // computations
    t++;
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
  unsigned t,i=0;
  for(t=0;t<RANGE_STEP;t+=QUARTER)
  {
    thread_data_array[i].start      = t;
    thread_data_array[i].stop       = t+QUARTER;
    thread_data_array[i].re_fc      = RE_factors;
    thread_data_array[i].im_fc      = IM_factors;
    pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,routine,(void *)&thread_data_array[i]);
    i++;
  }
  for(i=0; i<NUM_THREADS; i++)
  {
     int rc = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
     if (rc)
     {
         fprintf(stderr, "failed to join thread #%u - %s\n",i, strerror(rc));
     }
  }
}
```

The problem that I am talking about is occurring in the routine of the thread inside the `for()` loop exactly with these two load instructions `RE_m256_fac = Re_fac[t];`and `IM_m256_fac = Im_fac[t];` the loaded data is not correct ... I think the index `t` is a local variable so no synchros is needed , or I am wrong?

Comment: what's `thread_data_array`?

Comment: `t` might be a local variable but the array `thread_data_array` that it's used to index is clearly shared across threads. Show how that is constructed, and verify that the for loop inside `routine()` is correct.

Comment: `thread_data_array` of type `thread_data` is used to passe the arguments of each thread and it is declared global (see the code edit please after the struct declaration). And I double checked the `for()` loop inside **routine** and it is working as expected.

Comment: @bnaecker : `thread_data_array` does not contain an index only but a bunch of parameters as you can see in the **struct** declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging it turned to be that since I am reading from a global shared array I have to use the mutex mechanism to prevent the mutual exclusion  as so:

```
void *routine(void *thread_info)
{
  int n,t;
  unsigned t_start,t_stop;
 __m256 *Re_fac    , *Im_fac;
 struct thread_data *mydata;
 mydata = (struct thread_data*) thread_info;
 t_start   = mydata->start;
 t_stop    = mydata->stop;
 Re_fac        = mydata->re_fc;
 Im_fac        = mydata->im_fc;

 t = t_start;
 for (n = t_start; n < t_stop; n += 8)
 {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   // computations
   RE_m256_fac = Re_fac[t];
   IM_m256_fac = Im_fac[t]; 
   // computations
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   t++;
 }
 pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

and since then, I can see that the threads are loading the values correctly from the shared array.